# Dev Express Grid control auto filter customization

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

How can I customize Dev Express Grid control's (win forms) auto filter text.

For example, how can I change "equals" text to "MyEqualsText"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to localize the text? If so, [this](http://www.devexpress.com/support/center/kb/p/a421.aspx) is the official way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ASPxGridView1.Columns[i].Caption="New Name";
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's always better to provide a short description for a sample code to improve the post accuracy :)